# In how many ways we can pair from given sets .

Tags: combinations

In how many ways we can make pairs (Both elements must be from different groups)
i.e. if we have two sets, 
$A=\{1,2\}$ and
$B=\{3,4\}$,
it's simple we can make $(1,3)$ $(2,4)$ $(1,4)$ $(2,3)$  only four pairs can be obtained

if we have 
$A=\{1,2,3,4\}$,
$B=\{5,6\}$,
$C=\{7,8\}$

I think we can make 20 pairs for them. correct me if I am wrong . and i need general formula for this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: you don't mention an order for the sets $A$, $B$ wich makes me think that $(3,1),(3,2),(4,1),(4,2)$ will also do in your example.

Comment: sorry for that (3,1) and (1,3) we have to consider both to be same

Answer (score 3):

The set of all possible **ordered** pairs is called the Cartesian product, symbolized by $\times$.

$$A \times B \equiv \{(a,b) \space | \space a \in A, b \in B \}$$

The number of pairs (number of elements in the product):

$$|A \times B| = |A||B|$$

Comment: Why do you subtract the intersection?

Comment: Because I got confused. Thanks. :)

Comment: does this mean just multiply the number of elements in a set like  4 x 2 x 2=16 ?

Comment: Unless you simply want to count 3-tuples, which obviously you don't, then you need realize that: *OK*, put $A$ to the left of $\times$. But now, do you put $B$ or $C$ to the right? maybe $B \cup C$? Think about it. (For 3 sets, just multiplying the 3 sizes *will* give you the correct number **only** when $B \cap C = \emptyset$)

Answer (score 0):

A more general way to construct the formula: 
Suppose that you have n sets, $A_1, \cdots A_n,$ where some element may be in more that one set.  An example would be to **revise** your original example  by changing $C$ from $\{7,8\}$ to $\{6,7\}.$

Let $f(A_i)$ denote the number of **distinct** elements in all of the $(n-1)$ sets **combined** other than $A_i.$ 
In the **revised** example, where $A_1$ is set to $A = \{1,2,3,4\},$ then
$f(A_1)$ would = 3.

Let $g(A_i)$ denote the number of (presumably distinct) elements in $A_i.$ 
Let $h(A_i)$ denote the number of elements in $A_i$ that are also in at least one of the (n-i) sets $A_{i+1}, \cdots, A_n.$

Then the possible number of ordered pairs will be
$\sum_{i=1}^n \{f(A_i) \times g(A_i)\} - h(A_i).$

The reason that $h(A_i)$ is relevant is best visualized by example.  Suppose that the original example is **further refined** so that $A_1 = \{1,2,5,6\}.$

Then, the normal formula $\sum_{i=1}^n \{f(A_i) \times g(A_i)\}$ would count (5,5) twice and count (6,6) **three times**.